# Zend Framework vs Drupal, or is the argument silly?

Tags: zend-framework, drupal

My friend thinks that Drupal is a much better framework than Zend, I however, think it's an unfair comparison.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: It would be more like Zend vs CakePHP/CodeIgniter/et al, and Drupal vs ExpressionEngine/Seagull/et al. And it would still not the right kind of question for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are two different products altogether. Drupal is not a framework, it is a [Content Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). This allows for distributed publishing, workflow and much more. It can be extended through plugins to provide additional functionality.

Zend Framework is a [web application framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework). It gives a common set of tools, services and code that can be used to build a site. It does not give you a site unless you put these items to some use first.

Think of it this way:
If you wanted to build a Content Management System like Drupal from scratch, you would use a Web Application Framework like Zend Framework to shortcut a lot of the standard elements you would need such as session management, email, database abstraction layer etc.

Comment: Zend is not a framework, Zend is a company. Zend Framework is a framework.